# Use latest SASS with @use in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, less

I want to use sass in my project.
I have "node-sass" and "sass-loader" installed, I can use imports, variables, and other future of sass but I can't use "@use" for using a @mixin or @function.

---

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
}
 "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5"
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1"
}
```

---

my code:
grid.scss

```css
@use 'sass:meta';
@use 'sass:map';
@use './config';

@mixin col($ratio) {
  flex: 0 0 $ratio;
  max-width: $ratio;
}

@mixin grid($from, $size, $cols) {
  $breakpoint-size: map.get(config.$breakpoint-sizes, $from);

  @media (min-width: $breakpoint-size) {
    .grid-#{$from}-#{$size} {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;

      @each $col in $cols {
        > .col-#{$from}-#{$col} {
          @include col(math.percentage($col / $size));
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

@mixin grids($grid-definitions...) {
  @each $breakpoint, $grid-definition in meta.keywords($grid-definitions) {
    @if not map.has-key(config.$breakpoint-sizes, $breakpoint) {
      @error '"#{$breakpoint}" must be one of (#{config.$breakpoints}).';
    }

    @if not map.has-key($grid-definition, size) {
      @error '"#{$breakpoint}" grid must have a "size" key.';
    }

    @if not map.has-key($grid-definition, cols) {
      @error '"#{$breakpoint}" grid must have a "cols" key.';
    }

    @include grid(
      $from: $breakpoint,
      $size: map.get($grid-definition, size),
      $cols: map.get($grid-definition, cols)
    );
  }
}
```

use:

```css
@use "assets/scss/grid";
    @include grid.grids(
      $xs: (
        size: 1,
        cols: (1)
      ),
      $md: (
        size: 2,
        cols: (1)
      ),
      $xl: (
        size: 4,
        cols: (1)
      ),
      $xxl: (
        size: 5,
        cols: (1)
      ),
    );
```

---

ERROR:

> in ./pages/sign-in/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=d2289462&lang=scss&scoped=true& (./node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@4.3.0_webpack@4.46.0/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/.pnpm/vue-loader@15.9.7_559ffc97fd41de05d12663d7fb949156/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@3.0.0/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@10.2.0_node-sass@4.14.1/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/.pnpm/vue-loader@15.9.7_559ffc97fd41de05d12663d7fb949156/node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./pages/sign-in/index.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=d2289462&lang=scss&scoped=true&)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@10.2.0_node-sass@4.14.1/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> SassError: Invalid CSS after "@include grid": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was ".grids("
> on line 125 of pages/sign-in/index.vue
> @include grid.grids(

I installed sass `yarn add -D sass` then the problem was solved but I have some errors in the terminal,
I think this error is for bootstrap, but I didn`t know how to fix these errors.

---

[image]

Comment: As far a I know, if you want to use the latest SASS, you need to install **dart-sass** with `yarn add -D sass` rather than the usual **node-sass**. https://github.com/sass/dart-sass#from-npm

Comment: that's worked but I have "86 repetitive deprecation warnings omitted." warning in my terminal @kissu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, installing the proper dart package (`sass`) solved it, as [explained here](https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div).

Then, we need to update the deprecation warnings, most of them are detailed here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes

As for the warning, you could:

- look into the Bootstrap package you're using and ask the question in their Github issues
- try to have your own version of the package (not a good idea IMO)
- just ignore this, since it's a warning it's not a blocker. It will be an issue at `v2.0.0` but as of right now, their latest is still not that close so I guess that this will not happen before some good time

Comment: For bootstrap errors, I used the latest version of bootstrap (5.0.2) and the errors were fixed.