# How to setup SASS/SCSS/sass-loader in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

[image]

I have a Nuxt app and I want to use the CSS pre-processor.
I installed the `sass-loader` fibers dependencies, but after installation, a message appears in the application console, which I presented in the image and in the code

This is code err:

```
 WARN  webpack@5.49.0 is installed but ^4.46.0 is expected                                                                                                                                                                     17:22:44


 WARN  sass-loader@12.1.0 is installed but ^10.1.1 is expected

     


Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {                                                                                                                           17:22:46
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "/home/sergey/all_project/pro_projects_all_language/empty/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
      "options": {
        "configFile": false,
        "babelrc": false,
        "cacheDirectory": true,
        "envName": "server",
        "presets": [
          [
            "/home/sergey/all_project/pro_projects_all_language/empty/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js",
            {
              "corejs": {
                "version": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-29[0].rules[0].use[0]"
    }
  ]
}

  "use": [
  {
  "loader": "node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js",
  "options": {
  "configFile": false,
  "babelrc": false,
  "cacheDirectory": true,
  "envName": "server",
  "presets": [
  [
  "node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js",
  {
  "corejs": {
  "version": 3
  }
  }
  ]
  ]
  },
  "ident": "clonedRuleSet-29[0].rules[0].use[0]"
  }
  ]
  }
  at checkResourceSource (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:167:11)
  at Function.normalizeRule (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:198:4)
  at node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:110:20
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.normalizeRules (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:109:17)
  at new RuleSet (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:104:24)
  at new NormalModuleFactory (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
  at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:636:31)
  at Compiler.newCompilationParams (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:653:30)
  at Compiler.compile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:661:23)
  at node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:77:18
  at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:24:1)
  at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
  at Watching._go (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:41:32)
  at node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:33:9
  at Compiler.readRecords (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:529:11)
```

I tried reinstalling dependencies, reinstalling a completely clean Nuxt application, and still the problem remains.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To install SASS in Nuxt, you have to run `yarn add -D sass sass-loader@10.1.1` (or `npm i -D sass-loader@10.1.1 --save-exact && npm i -D sass`).

The version of `sass-loader` needs to be exact and set at the latest `10.x.x` because the next one (`11.0.0`) is using Webpack5, hence being a breaking change because Nuxt2 is only running on Webpack4 as shown here: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases

**IF** then, you still cannot use `<style lang="sass">` in your `.vue` components, then proceed.

---

Add this to your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  build: {
    loaders: {
      sass: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
      },
      scss: {
        implementation: require('sass'),
      },
    },
  }
}
```

Here is a [working repo](https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-working-sass-scss) with the latest recommended `sass` ([dart-sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass)) setup working properly with this kind of code

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="test">
      Hello there
    </span>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
div
  .test
    color: red
</style>
```

PS: if SASS is properly installed, then SCSS is working as good because it's basically the same thing.

---

If you have some warning on some things being deprecated like `/ for divison` or any listed here: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes
You can refer to this answer for a fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648204/8816585

Comment: I have been writing on Nuxt for 1 year now. I have always used scss, I have a project, everything works there, but I wanted to change the concept of the application and decided to rewrite some binders, and in my empty project, when I do <style lang= "scss" scoped>< / style> - it says an error, I can also show it, but it is already different from the one I have just given. And I used the Nuxt documentation, but still nothing helped. I did as you said, I have the same error... Can you try to install a clean project and do the same thing and say the result?

Comment: I do not doubt your qualifications) The fact is that I know how to work with SASS and SCSS, I have already worked with them for a long time, but I have an error when starting the application, I have not even written style in the component yet. And the application does not start anymore.

Comment: I ask the messenger to show a video from the screen, what happens and when

Comment: The profile was essentially for you to contact me. I don't know what is your setup and what you're used to but I can at least give you a working setup (present in my answer). For you to then investigate and find out where is the issue coming from on your side. @dotenv9

Comment: what about `nuxt3`?

Comment: @NtwariClaranceLiberiste not sure, didn't tried it myself.

Comment: I have a similar problem but fixes here didn't work please refer to my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74798698/nuxt-build-errors-sass-loader-related-when-running-run-build-but-run-dev-comp?noredirect=1#comment132008966_74798698

Answer (score 0):

kissu's answer worked for me, but not right away. Finally I managed to fix the problem by downgrading the loader also followed by removing and installing again nuxt.

Comment: Strange that you needed to do that one. Glad it works at least!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Sass loader in Nuxt 3, just use this command to install sass in Nuxt 3:

```
npm install sass --save-dev
```

For Nuxt 2 you need the sass loader, try this for Nuxt 2:

```
npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10
```