# Error after added Nuxt to my vue project (vue-style-loader css error)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Help me please. Added Nuxt(SSR) to the my vue project. All moved to the root of the project, created a page folder. The following error appeared:

```
 ERROR in ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&)
    Module build failed (from ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js):
    ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
     - options.modules has an unknown property 'compileType'. These properties are valid:
       object { auto?, mode?, exportGlobals?, localIdentName?, localIdentRegExp?, context?, hashPrefix?, getLocalIdent? }
        at validate (/app/node_modules/css-loader/node_modules/schema-utils/dist/validate.js:98:11)
        at Object.loader (/app/node_modules/css-loader/dist/index.js:36:28)
     @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css& (./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--3-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&) 4:14-327
     @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=css&
     @ ./.nuxt/components/nuxt-loading.vue
     @ ./.nuxt/App.js
     @ ./.nuxt/index.js
     @ ./.nuxt/client.js
     @ multi ./.nuxt/client.js
```

[image]

code from `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'

export default {
  alias: {
    style: resolve(__dirname, './assets/style'),
  },
}
```

As I understand the error is related to the setting of the Nuxt.

Comment: Is everything in your `package.json` using Webpack4 and Vue2? Also, did you moved some of the Vue config into the Nuxt one?

Comment: @kissu Hi, I use vue 2(without webpack (vue cli)).
Here is my configs - https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-sea-8ocon?file=/package.json

Comment: I have same bug , can you show package.json (devDependencies ,dependencies) ?

Comment: @Mm.Mirzaei.dev Hi, Here it - https://gist.github.com/harddownloader/f80c300da13fff71166a7bbfeb3baed7

Comment: @Mm.Mirzaei.dev please follow this one or ask a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `package.json` you do have `sass-loader` set to `^12.1.0`, meanwhile the package introduces a [breaking change during `v11.0.0`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/releases/tag/v11.0.0).

It requires Webpack5, which Nuxt is not compatible as of today. If you downgrade it down to `v10.1.1` (and all related packages like `node-sass`), you should be fine.

Comment: it's work! Thank you!
Here's what I did (I installed sass and css loader, which support webpack4 ):
1) yarn remove node-sass sass-loader css-loader
2) yarn add node-sass@4.14.1
3) yarn add sass-loader@v10.1.1 -D
4) yarn add css-loader@5.2.7 -D