# Nuxtjs site deploy fails in Netlify when using sass/scss + fibers

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, netlify, fibers

The deploy fails on Netlify whenever I include any SCSS. If I take out the SCSS it deploys fine. It runs fine locally.

You can easily recreate this by pulling the repo here https://github.com/jackcunningham/sasstest
or with a fresh nuxt install with:
`javascript`, `npm`, no frameworks, `pwa`, no linting or testing, `ssr`, `static`, `jsconfig.json` and `git`

from there install sass with fibers as per the nuxt docs here https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-css/

`#npm install --save-dev sass sass-loader@10 fibers`

You can test by adding a scss block to the bottom of the pages/index.vue like

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.home {
  h1 {
    color: yellow;
  }
}
</style>
```

This runs fine locally and I can also `npm run build` and `generate`

but on Netlify  with `npm run generate` it fails with

```
2:42:19 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:42:19 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
2:42:19 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
2:42:19 PM: ​
2:42:19 PM:   Error message
2:42:19 PM:   Command failed with exit code 134: npm run generate
2:42:19 PM: ​
2:42:19 PM:   Error location
2:42:19 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
2:42:19 PM:   npm run generate
2:42:19 PM: ​
2:42:19 PM:   Resolved config
2:42:19 PM:   build:
2:42:19 PM:     command: npm run generate
2:42:19 PM:     commandOrigin: ui
2:42:19 PM:     publish: /opt/build/repo/dist
2:42:19 PM:     publishOrigin: ui
2:42:20 PM: Caching artifacts
...
2:42:20 PM: Finished saving go dependencies
2:42:20 PM: Build failed due to a user error: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:42:20 PM: Creating deploy upload records
2:42:20 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
2:42:20 PM: Failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 2
2:42:20 PM: Finished processing build request in 34.120681685s
```

**Updated:** My dependencies look like the following, I've tried downgrading packages and node versions to match previous projects that work fine but it has no effect, so think this is a red herring but here they are

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/pwa": "^3.3.5",
    "core-js": "3.8.3" //downgraded from "^3.15.1",
    "nuxt": "2.14.12" //downgraded from "^2.15.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "fibers": "^5.0.0",
    "sass": "1.36.0" //downgraded from "^1.43.3",
    "sass-loader": "10.1.1" //downgraded form "^10.2.0"
  }
```

I also added the following to force the node version to match @kissu  version (see comments), but think this is not the issue

```
"engines": {
    "node": ">=14.15.0 <14.18.1"
  }
```

Comment: Does it locally?

Comment: it runs fine locally and can build / generate local fine too

Comment: i also found a thread here https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8771 which suggested downgrading to sass 1.36.0 and sass-loader 10.1.1  which I've tried with no success. Again works great locally but netlify deploy fails.

Comment: and this article https://sass-lang.com/blog/node-fibers-discontinued If i read this correctly maybe we can no longer use sass fibers?

Comment: Does this one help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585

Comment: alas no, I've tried specifying the versions mentioned and including the loaders. Repo is here https://github.com/jackcunningham/sasstest

Comment: Just in case it was an issue with node versions I've used engines inside my package.json to specify versions that work fine in another projects -  "node": "12.18.0", "npm": "6.14.4", taken from another project that deploys fine on Netlify with sass-loader running. I just tried deploying that site and it runs perfectly

Comment: What's the non working one versions ?

Comment: I updated above with the versions but it doesn't work whichever versions

Comment: so to clarify an older project with what seems like the same package versions works fine, but a fresh nuxt project with just sass + fibers installed, that runs fine locally, fails on netlify. Probably the easiest way to recreate is pull the repo or run through those steps and trying pushing up to netlify

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238487/discussion-between-codycustard-and-kissu).

Answer (score 0):

The latest LTS of Node is `14.18.1`, Netlify supports at least `v12`.
I downloaded [your project](https://github.com/jackcunningham/sasstest) while having `v14.15.0` and it works totally fine when I do remove your `engines` in `package.json`.

If I do install the project with your specific version `12.18.0` of Node, it still works fine [when hosted on Netlify](https://festive-murdock-e670fd.netlify.app/) (with `engines` untouched).

Also, I'm not sure why you do use a super specific version of Node, could maybe give a range here: https://itnext.io/node-engines-helping-developers-everywhere-avoid-phantom-bugs-2eef519604b2

TLDR: everything works totally fine so far on my side. The issue is maybe somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, completely stumped, even tried a different Netlify account and I get the same errors which fix as soon as i change scss > css. Currently stripping out all my scss so i can progress my project