# Using chainWebpack in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I'm trying to adapt a theme in Nuxt from a Vue Project which has the next prop in vue.config.js

```
  chainWebpack: config => {
    const modules = ['vue-modules', 'vue', 'normal-modules', 'normal']
    modules.forEach(match => {
      config.module
        .rule('sass')
        .oneOf(match)
        .use('sass-loader')
        .tap(opt => mergeSassVariables(opt, "'@/styles/variables.scss'"))
      config.module
        .rule('scss')
        .oneOf(match)
        .use('sass-loader')
        .tap(opt => mergeSassVariables(opt, "'@/styles/variables.scss';"))
    })
  },
```

I'm newbie in nuxt and I can't find a solution for adapting this, I read that could be written in the build prop of nuxt.config.js but I can't figure out how.

Someone can help me please?, I'm using nuxt 2.15.8.

Comment: You want to use SASS with Nuxt? Did you tried this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585

Comment: It's a function from @vuetify/cli-plugin-utils to like import the variables file in each module matched and yes i have sass and sass-loader installed.