# There is an issue with `node-fibers`

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js, vercel

I have now spent a good portion of my day trying to deploy my Nuxt project to Vercel but I keep getting this error:

```
## There is an issue with `node-fibers` ##
`/vercel/path0/node_modules_dev/fibers/bin/linux-x64-93-glibc/fibers.node` is missing.
Try running this to fix the issue: /node16/bin/node /vercel/path0/node_modules_dev/fibers/build
Error: Cannot find module '/vercel/path0/node_modules_dev/fibers/bin/linux-x64-93-glibc/fibers'
Require stack:
- /vercel/path0/node_modules_dev/fibers/fibers.js
- /vercel/path0/nuxt.config.js
```

I'm new to SASS and this is my first time deploying a project that has it configured in it. I have tried suggestions from other Stackoverflow posts but none of them seem to work.

What could I be doing wrong here? Is there something I could try to fix this?

Comment: Not sure if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585) is still relevant but you should probably look into the Node.js used here. Also, does it work locally? Did you tried on Netlify?

Comment: Thank you @kissu you saved my day! It worked after going with that setup in the post you referenced!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably caused by the SASS version used. You could check my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585) to have a guide on how to setup a proper configuration and be able to host it on Vercel.

`node-sass` is quite buggy and slow but since Nuxt3 is in RC3, people will be able to use the `sass` package (with either Vite or Webpack5).

In case SASS is needed at all (PostCSS is doing quite of the work as of today already).