# SCSS Compilation Issue in Vue.JS

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I'm creating a vue.js web app, and I'd like to use SCSS. I've installed `npm i node-sass sass-loader` and I've created a vue.config.js at root level:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "@/style.scss";`,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

[image]

All styles I have added in main.scss file and main.scss file are imported in style.scss file.

```scss
    @import './color';
    @import './mixin';
    @import './break-point';
    @import './common';
    @import './form';
```

My issue is that my web app doesn't load any of the .scss files or styles imported via the main style.scss file. I am not getting any error in console.

I have also created separate .scss files for every pages and imported style.scss in particular page CSS show in below image:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to import main *style.scss* file right inside of *App.vue* - in the end, like that (**@** - means **src** folder in your Vue project):

```
<style lang="scss" src="@/styles/style.scss"></style>
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried as you suggested but it's not working for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).