# Node 18.7.0 Can only have one resource source when compiling with nuxt

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I have the following package file

```json
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "node ./pm2.js",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "5.10.2",
    "@nuxtjs/style-resources": "1.0.0",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "6.3.1",
    "axios": "0.19.2",
    "cheerio": "1.0.0-rc.2",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.6",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "geoip2ws": "1.8.10",
    "gsap": "2.1.3",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "mongoose": "5.9.10",
    "morgan": "1.10.0",
    "nuxt": "2.15.8",
    "pm2": "4.4.0",
    "request": "2.88.0",
    "sitemap": "2.2.0",
    "vcards-js": "2.10.0",
    "vuex-router-sync": "5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.18.10",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "7.18.9",
    "chokidar": "3.4.0",
    "eslint": "8.21.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.3.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.7.0",
    "normalize-scss": "7.0.1",
    "postcss-preset-env": "6.7.0",
    "sass": "1.54.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.7.0",
    "npm": "8.13.2"
  }
}
```

But upon running I get the following error

> | Error: Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and
> test + include + exclude) in { |   "use": [ |     { |       "loader":
> "/usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js", |
> "options": { |         "configFile": false, |         "babelrc":
> false, |         "cacheDirectory": true, |         "envName":
> "server", |         "presets": [ |           [ |
> /usr/src/app/node_modules/@nuxt/babel-preset-app/src/index.js, |
> { |               "corejs": { |                 "version": 2 |
> } |             } |           ] |         ] |       }, |
> "ident": "clonedRuleSet-30.use[0]" |     } |   ] | } |     at
> checkResourceSource
> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:167:11)
> |     at RuleSet.normalizeRule
> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuleSet.js:198:4)

I am not sure which package is causing this?

Comment: Nuxt works better with Node 16. Also, regarding the error it's more of a configuration thing than a `package.json` issue. Did you made any updates to that one recently? Btw, did you also tried that one maybe? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9268#issuecomment-836521127 [Lowering the version of `sass-loader`](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8771#issuecomment-774540158) may also be a good idea. Not sure why you do have both `sass` and `sass-loader` at the same time tbh. `moment` should be removed from the project overall (deprecated) but the rest seems quite okay to me.

Comment: This is also how to properly work with SASS: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585

Comment: Hi, any news @microman? I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxt works better with Node 16.

Also, regarding the error it's more of a configuration thing than a `package.json` issue. Did you made any updates to that one recently?

Btw, did you also tried that one maybe? https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9268#issuecomment-836521127

[Lowering the version](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8771#issuecomment-774540158) of sass-loader may also be a good idea. Not sure why you do have both `sass` and `sass-loader` at the same time tbh.
`moment` should be removed from the project overall (deprecated) but the rest seems quite okay to me.

---

This is also how to properly work with SASS: [How to setup SASS/SCSS/sass-loader in Nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728903/how-to-setup-sass-scss-sass-loader-in-nuxt/68730454#68730454)