# Nuxt build errors (sass loader related?) when running run build but run dev compiles

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

My repo for anyone to have a look: https://gitlab.com/gkurl/vapedcrusader

Node version 16.18.1.

Getting a nuxt build error when I run yarn run build (dev works fine):

```
ERROR in ./components/AppNavigation.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=15d18dee&prod&lang=scss& (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/AppNavigation.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=15d18dee&prod&lang=scss&)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 23
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/components/AppNavigation.vue:1:198660
    at Parser.error (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:127:11)
    at Parser.operator (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:162:20)
    at Parser.parseTokens (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:245:14)
    at Parser.loop (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:132:12)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:51:17)
    at parse (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:47:30)
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:333:24
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:194:18
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:139:18
    at Rule.each (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
    at Rule.walk (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:152:24
    at Root.each (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
    at Root.walk (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
    at Root.walkDecls (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:192:19)
    at transformProperties (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:330:8)
    at Object.syncTransform [as plugin] (/Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:522:5)
    at /Users/gkurl/Documents/vapedcrusader-frontend/vapedcrusader/node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:459:97
 @ ./components/AppNavigation.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=15d18dee&prod&lang=scss& (./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--7-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--7-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/@nuxt/components/dist/loader.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./components/AppNavigation.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=15d18dee&prod&lang=scss&) 4:14-450
 @ ./components/AppNavigation.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=15d18dee&prod&lang=scss&
 @ ./components/AppNavigation.vue
 @ ./layouts/default.vue
 @ ./.nuxt/App.js
 @ ./.nuxt/index.js
 @ ./.nuxt/client.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/@nuxt/components/lib/installComponents.js ./.nuxt/client.js

 FATAL  Nuxt build error                                                                                                                                                12:39:57

  at WebpackBundler.webpackCompile (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2127:21)
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at async WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2076:5)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules/@nuxt/builder/dist/builder.js:327:5)
  at async Object.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-build.js:110:7)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js:413:7)
```

Tried different sass-loader tweaks etc. Not to sure what the issue is. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Give a try to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68730454/8816585

Comment: @kissu thanks I have tried that but still getting the same error. Tried the build config and made sure sass-loader is the version specified. I'm using `lang=scss`. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: After commenting out some files and trying to single out via elimination - I think I have pinpointed the source. I am able to yarn build if I comment out a specific .scss file in my repo - mainly _2_dropdown.scss found in _3_mega-site-navigation.scss. Not sure if there is a scss method or something that nuxt isn't liking?