# sass-loader in Nuxt 2 is removing `@container`. How can I force it to keep it?

Tags: nuxt.js, webpack-4, sass-loader

I am creating an app using Nuxt 2. I am using sass-loader v.10.3.1 and Webpack 4 – I cannot use more recent versions as Nuxt 2 does not support sass-loader from v.11.

In my SCSS is use the following code:

```
@container (min-width: 25rem) 
    { 
        &__blockquote {
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
        } 
     }
```

On my dev version this works absolutely fine. However, once compiled for prod, sass-loader removes the container part and just applies `grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;`.

I'm wondering whether there is some kind of comment type code I can wrap around / put before the `@container` code block that forces it to be included even when sass-loader thinks it shouldn't. Hypothetically, something like this below whereby the comment `//sass` indicates to sass-loader that the immediately following code block should be compiled even if typically it would omit it:

```
//sass
@container (min-width: 25rem) {
    &__blockquote {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
    } 
}
```

I have tried updating sass-loader to a more recent version but, as stated, Nuxt 2 is not compatible so that didn't work (I discovered that in [this stack overflow answer about setting up sass-loader in nuxt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68728903/how-to-setup-sass-scss-sass-loader-in-nuxt)). Beyond that I have searched online, including here in SO, and checked the sass-loader docs but have been unable to find a solution.