# Using @use "sass:math" in a Vue component

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

In a Nuxt 2 project i have created a button component with the following style:

```css
<style lang="scss">
  .my-button {
    // lots of cool styles and stuff here
    $height: 28px;
    height: $height;
    border-radius: $height / 2;
    }
  </style>
```

The problem is the `border-radius: $height / 2;` line gives this warning:

```
    ╷
182 │     border-radius: $height / 2;
    │                    ^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    components/MyButton.vue 182:20  button-size()
    components/MyButton.vue 186:5   root stylesheet

: Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 
2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($height, 2)
```

It also links to [this page](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/breaking-changes/slash-div) describing the deprecation.

However if i add `@use "sass:math"` to the top of my style tag like so:

```css
  <style lang="scss">
    @use "sass:math";
    //Cool styles and stuff
    $height: 28px;
    height: $height;
    border-radius: math.div($height, 2);
  </style>
```

I get this error:

```
 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):                                                              12:13:59
SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
    ╷
102 │ @use "sass:math";
    │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
  components/MyButton.vue 102:1  root stylesheet"
```

I think i need to add the import of `@use "sass:math"` somewhere in `nuxt.config.js` file to load it in all components or similar, but i am not able to figure out where.

The css related blocks in my nuxt.config.js currently looks like:

```js
  build: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: {
        'postcss-easing-gradients': {},
      },
    },
  },
  styleResources: {
    scss: [
      '~/assets/global-inject.scss',
    ],
  },
  css: [
    '~/assets/base.scss',
    '~/assets/reset.scss',
  ],
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updating [@nuxtjs/style-resources](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/style-resources) to above version 1.1 and using `hoistUseStatements` fixed it.

I changed the `styleResources` object in `nuxt.config.js` to:

```js
styleResources: {
    scss: [
      '~/assets/global-inject.scss',
    ],
    hoistUseStatements: true,
  },
```

and added `@use "sass:math";` to the top of `global-inject.scss`.

Answer (score 3):

#### Updated answer

What if you try this in your `nuxt.config.js` file?

```js
{
  build: {
    loaders: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
          @use "@/styles/colors.scss" as *;
          @use "@/styles/overrides.scss" as *;
        `,
      },
    },
  ...
}
```

Or you can maybe try one of the numerous solutions here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/style-resources-module/issues/143

---

Plenty of people do have this issue but I don't really have a project under my belt to see what is buggy. Playing with versions and adding some config to the nuxt config is probably the way to fix it yeah.

---

Also, if it's a warning it's not blocking so far or does it break your app somehow?

---

#### Old answer

My answer here can probably help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68648204/8816585

It is a matter of upgrading to the latest version and to fix those warnings.

Comment: Well your answer explains the problem, my question is more related to how i solve it. Specifically in Vue components in a Nuxt setup. I have fixed the warnings coming from `.scss`-files, but not managed to fix them in my components.

Comment: @Lars you're talking about the `Using / for division is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0` issue or the `@use rules must be written before any other rules` one?

Comment: `@use rules must be written before any other rules` is the "main" issue. The rest of the question was primarily for describing how i got there.